# Fetch with Custom Headers inside React Server Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, http-live-streaming

Is it possible to make a fetch request with custom headers inside a React server component? I'm trying access a video stream url with custom headers.

This is the API I'm trying to stream the video from:

```
{
"status_code": 200,
"message": "Episode found",
"data": {
    "anime_id": 5,
    "number": 100,
    "title": "Episodio 100: La catena invisibile",
    "video": "https://cdn2.dreamsub.me/fl/eyeshield-21/100/SUB_ITA/480p?token=73UQpt6f00zRQWyDUeGbefNcrpi8qYA3Pk310BoXZi4I3MQzUSkia026Kf9rxnYV",
    "video_headers": {
        "host": "cdn.dreamsub.cc",
        "referer": "https://cdn2.dreamsub.me/fl/eyeshield-21/100/SUB_ITA/480p?token=73UQpt6f00zRQWyDUeGbefNcrpi8qYA3Pk310BoXZi4I3MQzUSkia026Kf9rxnYV"
    },
    "quality": "480",
    "format": "mp4",
    "locale": "it",
    "is_dub": false,
    "id": 485
},
"version": "1"
```

}

Comment: Which header are you trying to set?

Yes, it is possible to do it, but only for some headers (note CORS headers cannot be set in frontend), but sth like that would work I guess: `const getData=()=>{fetch('api - data - path' ,{ headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json' } }  .then(function(response){ console.log(response)return response.json();})` but make sure to really check the content type value or what accept header should be. Mabye it is MIME type or so.

Comment: I'm trying to set "host" & "referer" headers. I ran into issues doing a request with custom headers from the client side but I was wondering if it'd be possible in a server component? Unless I'm misunderstanding what a server component is.